# convert json to json add one more property

Tags: javascript

I have the following json file:

```
[{"genres":"Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":1,"title":"Toy Story (1995)"},{"genres":"Children|Fantasy|Musical\r","movieId":2017,"title":"Babes in Toyland (1961)"},{"genres":"Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":2253,"title":"Toys (1992)"}]
```

and I need to convert adding one more property`rate` with value = 0.

```
[{"genres":"Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":1,"title":"Toy Story (1995)","rate":0},{"genres":"Children|Fantasy|Musical\r","movieId":2017,"title":"Babes in Toyland (1961)","rate":0},{"genres":"Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":2253,"title":"Toys (1992)","rate":0}]
```

Comment: Parse it, add the property to the object, make it a JSON again.

Comment: Kamen Minkov how to add the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a loop for add property to object array

```
var myJson = [{"genres":"Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":1,"title":"Toy Story (1995)"},{"genres":"Children|Fantasy|Musical\r","movieId":2017,"title":"Babes in Toyland (1961)"},{"genres":"Comedy|Fantasy\r","movieId":2253,"title":"Toys (1992)"}];

myJson.forEach(function(item){
item.rate = 0;
});
```